# Is it possible to use a single table with multiple columns to get csv data for number of Jmeter thread groups?

Tags: excel, csv, jmeter

I need to get csv data from a excel sheet with number of columns. Each column should be taken for separate thread groups of a jmeter project. Is it possible. or do i have to create separate tables for each column in different excel sheets?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) works only with [CSV files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and these CSV files don't have "sheets".

If you have test data in Excel binary format it is still possible to access it in JMeter with the help of [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Apache POI libraries](https://poi.apache.org/), in this case you can implement whatever logic you want because you will have the full freedom in coding of reading data in Groovy.

Example code can be found in the following articles:

- [How to Implement Data Driven Testing in your JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-implement-data-driven-testing-in-your-jmeter-test)
- [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)